# Can someone walk me through this last step of a first order ODE?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-explanation

I've been doing first order ODE's all morning, and gotten this ODE:

[image]

To this point:

[image]

But I am well and truly stumped as to how we get an explicit expression of y from here. I tried taking reciprocals, adding zero, but I cannot seem to crack this problem. Can someone explain the process of how we go from:

$$\frac{y}{1-y} = Ae^{t^2/2} $$

to:

$$ y = \frac{Ae^{t^2/2}}{1+Ae^{t^2/2}} $$

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{y}{1-y} = Ae^{t^2/2} $$

$$y =  Ae^{t^2/2} - y  Ae^{t^2/2}$$

$$y + y  Ae^{t^2/2} =  Ae^{t^2/2} $$

$$y\left( 1 +   Ae^{t^2/2}\right) =  Ae^{t^2/2} $$

$$y =  \frac{Ae^{t^2/2}}{\left( 1 +   Ae^{t^2/2}\right)} $$

Comment: Ah, I see, that makes alot of sense, I wasn't seeing the factoring you could do when you brought the -yA part over. Thank you so much!